# On page load I am trying to unhide multiple dropdowns in a div if any of the dropdowns have an option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five hidden drop-downs in a div that are dynamically populated with an option selected if required by the data.

I need to display the drop-downs that have an option selected but not if the value is 0.

My code tried so far:

```
$('.sendingCriteria').each(function () {
    $(':selected', this).each(function (e) {
        let $this = $(this);
        if ($this.value() != 0) {
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

The CSS:

```
.timeOfDay,.dayOfWeek,.dayOfMonth,.mnthOfYr{
    display: none;
}

.freqSelectors{
    display:none;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="sendingCriteria">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <span class="bi bi-question-circle-fill" data-help="help5"></span>
        <div class="manualAuto">
            <div class="form-check form-switch manAuto">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="manAuto" id="manAuto" value="1" checked="checked">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="freqSelectors">
            <div class="freq">
                <label class="form-label" for="frequency">Frequency</label>
                <select id="frequency" name="frequency" class="form-select" aria-label="Select Frquency">
                    <option value="0">-- Select --</option><option value="d" selected="selected">Daily</option><option value="w">Weekly</option><option value="m">Monthly</option><option value="a">Annually</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="timeOfDay Daily Weekly Monthly Annually">
                <label class="form-label" for="timeOfDay">Time of Day</label>
                <select id="timeOfDay" name="timeOfDay" class="form-select" aria-label="Select Time">
                    <option value="0">-- Select --</option><option value="1">01:00</option><option value="2">02:00</option><option value="3">03:00</option><option value="4">04:00</option><option value="5">05:00</option><option value="6">06:00</option><option value="7">07:00</option><option value="8">08:00</option><option value="9">09:00</option><option value="10">10:00</option><option value="11">11:00</option><option value="12">12:00</option><option value="13">13:00</option><option value="14">14:00</option><option value="15" selected="selected">15:00</option><option value="16">16:00</option><option value="17">17:00</option><option value="18">18:00</option><option value="19">19:00</option><option value="20">20:00</option><option value="21">21:00</option><option value="22">22:00</option><option value="23">23:00</option><option value="24">24:00</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dayOfWeek Weekly Annually">
                <label class="form-label" for="dayOfWeek">Day of the Week</label>
                <select id="dayOfWeek" name="dayOfWeek" class="form-select">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option><option value="1">Monday</option><option value="2">Tuesday</option><option value="3">Wednesday</option><option value="4">Thursday</option><option value="5">Friday</option><option value="6">Saturday</option><option value="7">Sunday</option><option value="9">Week Day</option><option value="10">Weekend</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dayOfMonth Monthly Annually">
                <label class="form-label" for="dayOfMonth">Day of the Month</label>
                <select id="dayOfMonth" name="dayOfMonth" class="form-select" aria-label="Select Month">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">Last day</option><option value="33">First Monday</option><option value="34">First Tuesday</option><option value="35">First Wednesday</option><option value="36">First Thurday</option><option value="37">First Friday</option><option value="38">First Saturday</option><option value="39">First Sunday</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="mnthOfYr Annually">
                <label class="form-label" for="dmnthOfYr">Month of the Year</label>
                <select id="dmnthOfYr" name="dmnthOfYr" class="form-select">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option><option value="1">January</option><option value="2">February</option><option value="3">March</option><option value="4">April</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">June</option><option value="7">July</option><option value="8">August</option><option value="9">September</option><option value="10">October</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12">December</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="help help5" style="display: none;">Choose the frequency for generating this notificaton</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you're trying to show/hide individual `select` elements, but your CSS hides `div.freqSelectors` which contains all of them.  That means showing an individual `select` will have no effect, because the parent `div` is still hidden.  So let's remove that CSS.

Next, your code is trying to iterate over `$(':selected', this)`.  But in this context, the `this` you reference is `.sendingCriteria`, which is a `div`.  That will have no `selected` elements, so that will never match anything.

Instead, let's keep it simple - just iterate over each `select` in this container.  We can find those using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), which will search *down* the DOM for matching elements.

We test each value, same as your code, but since it is the `div` containing the select that is hidden, we need to target that to unhide it, not the select itself.  We can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to do that, it will search back *up* the DOM to find the closest matching element.

Note your code is iterating over every `.sendingCriteria` on the page.  Are there really more than 1?  If not, you can remove that entire loop, and just find the selects inside that element, like:

```
let $selects = $('.sendingCriteria').find('select');
```

Working snippet below (with much simplified HTML - we can demonstrate the functionality with [a minimal subset](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the HTML you included).

```js
$('.sendingCriteria').each(function () {
    let $selects = $(this).find('select');
    $selects.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != 0) {
            $(this).closest('div').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.timeOfDay,.dayOfWeek,.dayOfMonth,.mnthOfYr{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sendingCriteria">
    <div class="freqSelectors">
        <div class="freq">
            <label class="form-label" for="frequency">Frequency</label>
            <select id="frequency" name="frequency" class="form-select" aria-label="Select Frquency">
                <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="d" selected="selected">Daily</option>
                <option value="w">Weekly</option>
                <option value="m">Monthly</option>
                <option value="a">Annually</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="timeOfDay Daily Weekly Monthly Annually">
            <label class="form-label" for="timeOfDay">Time of Day</label>
            <select id="timeOfDay" name="timeOfDay" class="form-select" aria-label="Select Time">
                <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="14">14:00</option>
                <option value="15" selected="selected">15:00</option>
                <option value="16">16:00</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="dayOfWeek Weekly Annually">
            <label class="form-label" for="dayOfWeek">Day of the Week</label>
            <select id="dayOfWeek" name="dayOfWeek" class="form-select">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="1">Monday</option>
                <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```